# My config.xml has minSdkVersion as 16 but cordova build targets targetting android-23. Will it still work on a lower SDK android?

Tags: android, cordova

I have `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />` in **config.xml** but when it builds it says it’s targeting **android-23** and that i need to install that SDK. If I do what `cordova build` wants, will it still work on android with SDK 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it will work on 16 & above.

> **android:minSdkVersion**

An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

> **android:targetSdkVersion**

An integer designating the API Level that the application is targetting.

- With this attribute set, the application says that it is able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion), but was explicitly tested to work with the version specified here.
- Specifying this target version allows the platform to disable compatibility settings that are not required for the target version (which may otherwise be turned on in order to maintain forward-compatibility) or enable newer features that are not available to older applications.
- This does not mean that you can program different features for different versions of the platform—it simply informs the platform that you have tested against the target version and the platform should not perform any extra work to maintain forward-compatibility with the target version.

Comment: And how do you set that in a Ionic 2 app ?

Answer (score 1):

yes it works on android with minimum version as specified in preferences.